# Couchbase stats timed out

Tags: java, performance, couchbase

We have couchbase 3.0.1 running on production servers and are seeing this in the logs a couple of times a day:

`<0.48.53>:couch_log:error:44]dcp client (<0.59.53>): vbucket-seqno stats timed out after 2.0 seconds. Waiting...`

This has the effect of causing a timeout on our Java application:

```
 {"code":"OperationTimeoutException","msg":"error.message.OperationTimeoutException","debug":"Timeout waiting for value","uiEvent":"NONE","reqId":"1","timestamp":"2016-01-26 10:59:06"}
```

Is there a way to improve the efficiency of these stats or some other method I can use so that we arent seeing issues of this sort?

Comment: I suggest you monitor the GC logs of the server. A GC can easily take 2 seconds esp if the JVM isn't tuned, in which case you won't get a response while this is happening.

Comment: So you think this is a Java issue rather than couchbase?

Comment: It could be, though since couchbase uses Java it's not easy to make that distinction.  Just because an application uses Java doesn't mean it has to pause for a long time, but the way many applications are written this is often the case.  Looking at the GC pauses is a common place to start looking for the causes of pauses in the system.

Comment: I thought couchbase uses erlang/C++? My belief is that this is a couchbase rather than Java issue as all the Java apps react in the same way when this couchbase error is present

Comment: In that case, it could be my mistake, but I would check your Java client doesn't GC for 2 seconds which could trigger such a time out.

Comment: I confirm there is no Java code in Couchbase Server. it's now Erlang/C and Go.

Comment: You have nothing to worry about the couch_log. It happens and the server will retry. That being said I am not sure why it shows on the Java SDK. Are you doing explicit metrics call from your application?

Answer (score 0):

The Java timeout you're seeing is not likely caused by the DCP stats timeout.  It's probably more likely that you have some common cause for both effects.

I've seen behavior like this before in an environment where VM's were on an oversubscribed network and again in another environment where VMs had overcommitted memory.  The challenge is that logs in Couchbase Server or emitted by the SDK probably can't pinpoint the cause.  You'll need to use other utilities, if that's the cause.

Comment: Yes I couldnt find anything that was directly related within couchbase or the Java codebase. I cleaned up the boxes and now that there is a large amount of free disk space the issue seems to have been eliminated.

Not particularly happy that I dont have a concrete resolution or reason but struggling to replicate the issue

Answer (score 0):

Not found anything that is a suitable answer but creating more available disk space seems to have had quite a big impact. Best guess at an answer is that it was an IO issue and having more free space helped to alleviate that but this really is a guess!